# Неправильно отрабатывает CanFocus в Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi

Если кратко - есть форма на которой динамически создается фрейм. На фрейме размещен Edit. В какой то момент создается фрейм и устанавливается SetFocus для Edit следующим образом:

```
if Edit1.CanFocus then
  Edit1.SetFocus;
```

Но установка фокуса происходит до показа формы, соответственно в результате выполнения получаем следующую ошибку:

```
Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window
```

Вопрос: Может есть какое то стандартное решение, или исправленный вариант для CanFocus? Интересует больше вопрос почему некорректно отрабатывает CanFocus.

Comment: Ответ очевиден - нельзя установить фокус на окно которого не существует (Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window). Как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: В таком случае CanFocus должен был вернуть False и все отработало бы отлично =) Нашел report на сайте [http://qc.embarcadero.com](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=11229)

Comment: Тогда используйте

 try
...
 finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно так:

```
if Edit1.Showing and Edit1.Enabled then
  Edit1.SetFocus;
```

Документация [TWinControl.Showing](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Showing).

Comment: Да, пожалуй это лучшее решение. Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Выход очевиден:

```
if Edit1.Visible and Edit1.Enabled then
  Edit1.SetFocus;
```

Comment: Обе проверки возвращают true =).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась написанием собственного метода, который работает по аналогии с CanFocus, но дополнительно проверяет Parent форму на Visible и Enabled